# Load Balancing in Amazon Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing

Can anybody help me how to implement load balancing in Amazon EC2 instance ?

Thank s for the help in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taken from the Amazon ELB FAQ page:

- Launch the AWS Management Console
- Select Load Balancers from the left column of the management console.
- In the upper right pane, select “Create Load Balancer”
- Create a unique name for the Load Balancer.
- Select the protocol(s) to manage via the Load Balancer (HTTP, HTTPS, TCP, SSL, or Custom)
- Configure health checks for the Load Balancer.
- Select the instances that you wish to place behind the Load Balancer.
- Traffic to the DNS name provided by the Elastic Load Balancer is automatically distributed across your load balanced, healthy Amazon EC2 instances.

The ELB page can be accessed via http://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/

The benefits of Load Balancing are improved response times by sharing the work amongst a group of servers rather than just one. It also provides you with redundancy - if one server goes down there will still be others available to pick up the slack until the downed server comes back online.

Load balancing does introduce issues, and there are things that you have to be aware of. You have more complex scenarios for management, but in the end, load balancing is the only way to scale with regards to expanding past single hardware capability and in a lot of cases true automatic redundancy

Comment: Can you please mention the advantages of load balancing ?